# Print json array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print in browser console with JS my JSON response from PHP.
I saw many posts here and at another sites, but I can't do it.

I have a JSON like that

```
{"0":{"codigo_intervencao":"Apoio Emocional - 5270"},"1":{"tempo":"30"},"2":{"codigo_intervencao":"Apoio Emocional - 5270"},"3":{"tempo":"30"},"4":{"codigo_intervencao":"Apoio Emocional - 5270"},"5":{"tempo":"231518"},"6":{"codigo_intervencao":"Apoio Emocional - 5270"}}
```

I want to print in console, for example, each value of the key "codigo_intervencao", but I cannot achieve that.

I've tried something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $( "#target" ).click(function() {
    console.log("Select JS");
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "select.php",
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log("Response:" + response); // Here it prints above json
            var array = $.parseJSON(response);
            var tempo = 0;
            var arrayLength = array.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
              console.log(array[i]['codigo_intervencao']);

        }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I guess your JSON is an object, not an array. Try what `console.log(arrayLength)` gives you.

Comment: It gives me "undefined". So is it an object? How can I handle it?

Comment: You don’t have a `length` property. Iterate over [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) or [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead.

Comment: Several options: 1. If it is an array in PHP, use PHP's `json_encode()` to get an array in JavaScript. 2. Check if you need `$.parseJSON()` at all. 3. Try `for...in`: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp

Comment: try `console.table(array)`

Comment: Here's an example I put together before this thread was closed: https://jsbin.com/netexuh/edit?js,console

Answer (score 2):

You have a JSON object not an array.

```
var elements = $.parseJSON(response)
for (element in elements){
    console.log(elements[element]['codigo_intervencao'])
}
```

Iterate the JSON and get element you want.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON example you provided would parse to an Object. You could try something like:

```
const data = JSON.parse(response);
const array = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);
array.forEach(item => console.log(item.codigo_intervencao))
```

You'll get undefined for the objects that don't have the `codigo_intervencao` key. Alternatively you could iterate through your object with for..in.